# Remove rows from dataframe if they contain a certain value (R ,dplyr)

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe, df. I would like to remove all rows that contain the value 0 from the dataframe.

```
  ID     Value

  A      8
  A      8
  A      0
  B      1
  B      2
  C      0
```

Desired outcome:

```
 ID     Value

 A      8
 A      8
 B      1
 B      2
```

Here is the dput:

```
 structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
 "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Value = c(8L, 8L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 0L
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

This is what I tried:

```
 I was using the same concept to remove a column:

 library(dplyr)
 df%>% select(-c() 

 However, I am unsure how to specify how to remove the row if and only if it contains a 0.
```

Comment: df %>% filter(Value!=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `filter` instead of `select` as `select` is for selecting the columns while `filter` does the opposite i.e. keep/remove the rows

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter(Value!=0)
  #or filter(as.logical(Value))
```

---

In `base R`

```
subset(df, as.logical(Value))
```

Using `as.logical` also works as it converts the values to TRUE/FALSE i.e. all 0's will be FALSE and any  other than that will be TRUE